# In output PDF, first letter after \iftoggle condition is removed

Tags: etoolbox

When iftoggle condition is used,  first letter after the condition is removed in the output. Consider below code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\newtoggle{test}
\toggletrue{test}
First sentence.\iftoggle{test}{ Second sentence.} Last sentence.
\end{document}
```

If one executes above code, it renders `"First sentence. Second sentence.ast sentence."` removing "L"!. Can any one tell me how to correct it?

Comment: Please provide a complete mwe. However iftoggle has three arguments! The first one is the toggle name the second one your group `{ .. }` and the third one your `L`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The test `iftoggle` is a command with three mandatory arguments with the following syntax:

```
\iftoggle{ name }{ true }{ false }
```

> Expands to `true` if the state of the boolean flag `name` is true, and to
>   `false` otherwise.

In your example you have the following test:

```
\iftoggle{test}{ Second sentence.} Last sentence
```

with this setting:

```
name  ==> test
true  ==> Second sentence.
false ==> L
```

This happens because a standard mandatory argument is braced by curly brackets or it can be a single token.